# Serve aspx/ashx files as STATIC on Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I'm moving a static archived website to Apache from IIS/Windows, want to keep the old URLs that end with `.aspx`

How do I allow aspx/ashx as **static** content on Linux?

I don't plan to execute these files in Mono or anything, just to serve them as static (with all the code removed obviously, keeping only html)

I assume I should be doing something like this to my .htaccess:

```
AddType text/html .aspx
```

Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> AddType text/html .aspx
> ```

That should be OK. Does it work? Although best added to your server-config, rather than `.htaccess`, if possible.

Alternatively, you can rename the physical (static) files to `.html` (which is, after all, what they are) and *internally rewrite* the request from `.aspx` to `.html` for backwards compatibility using mod_rewrite. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite .aspx URLs to .html files
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)\.aspx$ /$1.html [L]
```